# rtp and rtsp player integration to browser

Tags: rtsp, rtp

I am trying to build a web service that will stream music over a web browser.
I got a server running to open up a web page that says "hello world".
The problem is that I do not understand what I need to put in the web page to start a rtp session.
I understand that I need some sort of player on the web page I'm opening but I do not understand how to make that player or how to show it up on the web page.
can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little late to the party here, but ...

You will need a player of some kind.

Currently, the browsers do not support playing a live RTP stream.  I've done some work in this area and it has required that I transcode the video to FLV for it to be viewable in many of the free flash players (i.e. JWPlayer, Flowplayer, etc.).

You could also write a custom browser plugin to read the RTP stream and display it in the browser but that would be sizeable undertaking.

Comment: I don't think JWPlayer supports RTSP, does it?